# Segue not working (anymore)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I do not know much about segues but I've got it working.. but suddenly it doesnt work anymore....

My code seems to work but the segue doesn't happen:

```
NSLog(@"login started");
if ([user_temp]) {
    NSLog(@"login success!");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginsuccess"];
}
```

Console output:

```
2015-01-31 21:35:27.321 Vertretungsplan[6753:3122243] login started
2015-01-31 21:35:27.321 Vertretungsplan[6753:3122243] login success!
```

but the segue doesn't appear? (It's just a snippet,I reduced the code...)

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the segue doesn't exist (id changed?). There are certain methods where you can query an object if it has a specific method.

Comment: @ott-- id? the identifier? it does exist..

Comment: It might help if you add a screenshot of your storyboard with the segue selected showing your identifier. Also, if you don't know much about segues, you can always read the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/index.html

Comment: Add NSLog() statements, one in the very first line in the segue and one after the performSegue...

Comment: @YuchenZhong user_temp is a PFUser from Parse...

Comment: What's the **suddenly** not working, @Tim? What did you do and then it becomes not working?

Comment: @ott-- changed the code to:                                                                                                `NSLog(@"login success 1");
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginsuccess" sender:self];
NSLog(@"login success 2");` console output: `2015-01-31 22:33:03.397 Vertretungsplan[6820:3135247] login started
2015-01-31 22:33:03.822 Vertretungsplan[6820:3135247] login success 1`

Comment: Is `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` being called? Are you returning `NO`?

Comment: @YuchenZhong nothing special... i worked on a tabbar viewcontroller, Ive wanted to try it... but i couldnt log in..

Comment: @RoboticCat still no segue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of following things

1. Identifier is valid.
2. You are performing segue on main thread.

   ```
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) withObject:@"loginsuccess" waitUntilDone:NO];
   ```

Comment: Ok, I tried but Im getting this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Vertretungsplan 0x15e88e800> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key storyboard.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182fb259c 0x1937080e4 0x182fb2220 0x183dbdb10 0x187a305d0 0x182edf3c0 0x187b6f83c 0x187d2f4d8 0x187d32ac0 0x183e85df0 0x182f6a9ec 0x182f69c90 0x182f67d40 0x182e950a4 0x18c0375a4 0x1877ca3c0 0x1000a30ac 0x193d76a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Try this, In prepareForSegue method add this condition 
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginsuccess"]) {
// Write your code here
}